# Multiple XML sources to OLE DB in SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, ssis

I have a bunch of different xml souces (over 100), and I am trying to pipe them all into an OLE DB via SSIS. I started out trying to use the Union All function, but since not all of the data that goes into each row of the database is of the same type, some of the values are entered in as "ignore" by SSIS, and come out as null. Each xml source has multiple outputs as well, so I am trying to avoid manually pointing each node of each xml source at a different db source, and then combining them. I know that you can change the input type of the data in the xml source under the advanced options, but there doesn't appear to be a way to default everything to one data type (string would work for me). Is there a way to use the union all feature to work for me, or a better way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are all the xml's have same schema. If they are then you can use foreach loop container.

Comment: No, every xml document has a different schema

Comment: currently i don't see any workaround except manually changing data types in advanced option for each xml source or you can use script task and write custom script to handle these xml sources in your code using LINQ.

Comment: Yea, that is what I assumed. I just hoped there might be a better way. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Does your server have access to folder that contains xml files?
If it does, using SSIS for that is not nesessary. Just use [OPENROWSET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522655.aspx)
Also you can make stored procedure that selects data from all xml sources and union all results. This SP you can use in your SSIS package.

Comment: I'm using a script task in ssis to create these xml documents, and the server does not have access to the directory where the xml is stored.